# X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN: Unable to embed Zeppelin notebook/paragraph to website

Tags: iframe, embed, apache-zeppelin, x-frame-options

According to resources I found on google, because of X-Frame-Options set to SAMEORIGIN, it will not be possible for me to embed my Zeppelin visualizations to another website.

When I checked the **zeppelin-site.xml.template**, the part where x-frame-options is defined in a property tag is commented.

```
<!--
<property>
  <name>zeppelin.server.xframe.options</name>
  <value>SAMEORIGIN</value>
  <description>The X-Frame-Options HTTP response header can be used to indicate whether or not a browser should be allowed to render a page in a frame/iframe/object.</description>
</property>
--->
```

However, in Chrome, when I inspect I found [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qumF.jpg)

Help.

Comment: This has been solved by downloading the 'Ignore X-Frame headers' extension for chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and due to a security the add extensions in Chrome was disabled.
 Therefore, in order to see the zeppelin reports:

1. copy the zeppelin-site.xml.template to zeppelin-site.xml
2. in the configuration file zeppelin-site.xml add zeppelin.server.xframe.options proprety with blank value (meaning nothing)

The browser doesn't recognize the header and will ignore it. 
But you'll get your chart in the web site :).

The browser complains with "Invalid 'X-Frame-Options' header encountered when loading http://" '' is not a recognized directive. The header will be ignored".

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options, you can set up the for X-Frame-Options value to 
ALLOW-FROM https://example.com/.

Choose the solution that does fit your scenario.
I hope it helps.